# C# - Creating variable dynamically to get each variable value

Tags: c#

I'm going to need to have a list which the size of the list is depended on a JSONArray. Thus I need to create some slider according to the size of the list. I can get make the slider dynamically according to JSONArray's list, but I can't take their value to be processed later. Many thanks for your help! Here is my attempted code:

```
private void generateDynamic()
{
    Listbox lb = new Listbox();
    for (int i = 0; list.count; i++)
        {
           StackPanel stackpanel = new StackPanel();
           Slider slider = new Slider();
           stackpanel.Children.Add(slider);
           lb.Items.Insert(i, stackpanel);
        }
}

private void onSaveValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // need to save each slider's value here
}
```

Comment: There's really nowhere near enough information in here to help you solve the problem. Please share your input and expected output, as well as the attempts you've made so far and explain why they fall short.

Comment: I want to make exactly like this http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC622504.png but make it dynamically using loop statements. I have done making it by loop statement, but I can't access each of them because they share the same variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Start by converting your JSONArray into a C# typed collection. Then you will be able to leverage two-way binding directly in XAML.

1. Add a ListBox to your View
2. Set the ItemSource property to your collection
3. Define an ItemTemplate containing your StackPanel + Slider (check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx))
4. Bind the Slider value to your object...
5. Done...